Why are there two points going to the node in the normalization?
Define a node to be a double point (a point of multiplicity 2) of a plane curve with distinct tangent directions. (See Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry I, exercise 5.6).
In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry III 9.7.1 page 258, he considers a curve $Y$ with a node, and $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ its normalization. After reading an answer of this example, I am still confused why there are exactly two points $P_1, P_2$ going to the node $Q$.
I know that the normalization and blowup has there own universal property. But I do not think the methods that prove there are two points of the blowup going to $Q$ can prove there are two points in the normalization going to $Q$. I doubt whether the two universal properties give that the normalization and blowup are the same.

See exercise 10.7.E in Vakil

@DavidLui, there are many versions of Vakil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry". Can you point out the chapter and section names so that I can check the exercise. An exhibition of the exercise is much better.

the most recent version: July 27, 2024 version.

@DavidLui, I have proved the statements in exercise 10.7.E in Vakil. But I think that method can not be applied to a general curve with a node. In that exercise, the equation $y^2- x^2(x+1)$ is too simple.

What is your definition for a curve with a node? There are many definitions and some are easier to work with than others, but all should imply that there are two points in the normalization above the node.

I don't actually know. Since 9.7.1 is an example instead of a theorem, I think that it's sufficient to just give a single example, and $y^2 - x^2 (x+1)$ is an example.

In chapter I, Exercise 5.6(b) Hartshorne defines a node as a double point with distinct tangent directions (referring to Exercise 5.3. for the definition of tangent directions). Can you use that?
